# Making a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, parse-platform

I have an object taken from Parse and I want to save its columns into a `Dictionary` or something else (if it's better).

I want to have a Dictionary like this: `["name" : "Mike", "lastname" : "vorisis", "id" : "advsas"]`

Below is the code I use to take my results:

```
func queryEvents() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "eventController")
    query.limit = 1000
    query.includeKey("idEvent")
    query.includeKey("eventType")
    query.includeKey("idEvent.idMagazi")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error)-> Void in
        if let objects = objects  {
            for object in objects {
                var post = object["idEvent"] as? PFObject
                var post2 = post!["idMagazi"]
                print("retrieved related post: \(post2["name"]!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found it out how can i do it.

I use a struct with what I want like this:

```
var userDictionary = [Int : Event]()
struct Event {
        var nameEvent: String
        var nameMagazi: String


    }
```

And then i use this:

```
  if let objects = objects  {
                for object in objects {

                    let post = object["idEvent"] as? PFObject
                    let post2 = post!["idMagazi"] as? PFObject

                    let nameEvent = post!["name"] as! String
                    let idEvent = post?.objectId
                    let nameMagazi = post2!["name"] as! String

                     self.events[self.i] = Event(nameEvent: nameEvent , nameMagazi: nameMagazi)

                    self.i += 1
                }
                print(self.events[1]!.nameEvent)
            }
```

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: `print(self.events[1]!.nameEvent)` will crash your application if there are less than 2 elements in the result. `self.events` should be an array instead of a dictionary with indexes as key. `self.i` could be a standard variable instead of an instance property. If you want to iterate with indexes, you can use `for (index, object) in objects.enumerate()` instead of manually incrementing an index.

Answer (score 6):

*Something else (if it's better)* is a custom class.
Change the type of `idMagazi` to the real type.

```
class Event {

  let post : PFObject
  let name : String
  let idMagazi : String

  init(object : PFObject) {
    self.post = object
    self.name = object["name"] as! String
    self.idMagazi = object["idMagazi"] as! String

  }
}
```

And use it

```
 ...
 if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]  {
    var events = [Event]()
    for object in objects {

      let post = Event(object: object)
      events.append(post)
      print("retrieved related post: \(post.name)")
    }
 }
 ...
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift `Dictionary<T,V>` is equivalent to `[T: V]`. Type is inferred if not explicitly declared.

Empty dictionary creation (all equivalent):

```
var dict1: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]
var dict2: [String: String] = [:]
var dict3 = Dictionary<String, String>()
var dict4 = [String: String]()
```

Dictionary with values (all equivalent):

```
var dict5 = ["Foo": "Bar", "Foo1": "Bar1", "Foo2": "Bar2"]
var dict6: Dictionary<String, String> = ["Foo": "Bar", "Foo1": "Bar1", "Foo2": "Bar2"]
var dict7: [String: String] = ["Foo": "Bar", "Foo1": "Bar1", "Foo2": "Bar2"]
```

Add values to an existing dictionary:

```
dict["Foo"] = "Bar"
```

---

In your specific scenario, you could use this:

```
let dict = ["name" : name, "lastname" : lastname , "id" : id]
```

where `name`, `lastname` and `id` are `String` variables.

---

#### Update based on [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38220992/469218):

Having this struct:

```
struct Event {
    var nameEvent: String
    var nameMagazi: String
}
```

You can use this approach, that avoid having an external index and uses an array instead of a dictionary for storing the results.

```
var events: [Event]?

guard let objects = objects else { return }
events = objects.map { object in
    let post = object["idEvent"] as? PFObject
    let post2 = post!["idMagazi"] as? PFObject

    let nameEvent = post!["name"] as! String
    let idEvent = post?.objectId
    let nameMagazi = post2!["name"] as! String

    return Event(nameEvent: nameEvent , nameMagazi: nameMagazi)
}
```

Comment: Curiosity: is any one of these methods considered idiomatic Swift? Do they all compile to the same underlying assembly, or is one method of creating an empty dictionary somehow more performant/faster?

Answer (score 3):

Create dictionary like this:

```
var dict = ["name" : "Mike", "lastname" : "vorisis" , "id" : "advsas"]
```

OR

```
var dict = Dictionary<String,String>
dict.setValue("Mike", forKey: "name")
```

Comment: Stop using `setValue:forKey:` unless you know exactly why you're using KVC.

Comment: @vadian sure, its not necessary to use setValue, I just showed the other way to set value. Thanks for the head up though.

Comment: Apart from that a Swift `Dictionary` does not respond to `setValue:forKey` at all the *other (swiftier) way* is `dict["name"] = "Mike"`

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can be made using this line:

```
var dictionaryArray: [Dictionary<String,String,Int>] = []
```

Then values can be added by appending them to the dictionary.

```
dictionaryArray.append(["name" : "Mike", "lastname" : "vorisis" , "id" : "advsas"])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all this is an `Array` rather than a `Dictionary`, and second of all it won't compile because of too many parameters.

Comment: It is an array of dictionaries which is what I believe needs to be used. If not then iAnurag's answer should work better.

Comment: Nevertheless a generic `Dictionary` with three types (`key`, `value`, `??`) doesn't work.

Comment: Naming an array variable `dictionary` makes baby Jesus cry.

Comment: Updated hopefully it's a bit better for you @redent84